# Getting a simple YUI <select> element example working

Tags: yui, jsfiddle

Just starting off with YUI and I'm struggling a bit.

I am very interested in the example: Button Control: Using A Menu Button To Replace A  Element here http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/button-menu-select_log.html .

The example seems very well documented and explained, but I am struggling to get it to work in jsfiddle or codepen.

I guess that I am not sure on how to start the javascript.

What I've been doing is copying and pasting the HTML, CSS, and Javascript into jsfiddle, but I think there is something missing along the lines of `YUI().use('node', function (Y) {`

I was wondering if someone could maybe take that example and pop it in a jsfiddle or codepen for me, I really have tried very hard to help myself but now feel a bit hopeless.

FWIW I even struggle to get a simple YUI 'Hello World' example going in jsfiddle.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Please the the jsfiddle link so that we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: OK, Akshar, please hang on I will make one in a minute.

Comment: Thanks, I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/LzTP7/

Comment: Nevermind fellas, I figured this out myself.
http://jsfiddle.net/4yzgk/6/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well that example is YUI2, not YUI3, so it's not going to work unless you wrap it in a yui use and bring them in that way [YUI 2 in YUI 3](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-yui2.html)

Comment: thanks kevin. jsfiddle supports YUI2 also thoug? I'm not concerned about what I am using. I would just love to see how someone gets that example to work.